# Facing issue while installing Modsecurity(version 2.9) in Rhel(version 5.6) with apache(version 2.4.18)

Tags: apache, mod-security, rhel5

Getting the below issue while installing the "modsecurity-2.9.1" on RHEL 5.6 having apache version 2.4.18.
[root@pysdcstg1070308 bin]# ./apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 536 of /root/Apache-2.4.18/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 4 of /root/Apache-2.4.18/apache/conf/mod_security.conf: Cannot load /root/Apache-2.4.18/apache/modules//mod_security2.so into server: /root/Apache-2.4.18/apache/modules/mod_security2.so: undefined symbol: ap_get_server_version

following the steps in the below link for installation:
http://blog.astaz3l.com/2015/02/19/apache-mod-security/

Have searched for possible soluting in stack overflow and other sites as well and googled , but could not find proper solution.
Please help.